# While Adding chartboost ads in unity getting error of google play servces could not be found

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, chartboost

I'm trying to add chartboost ads into my unity project, after adding app id and app signature when i click on setup android sdk i got this pop screen which shows the error google play services could not be found see the screen shot below..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you included Google Play Services in your Android Manifest? The button you mentioned should automatically install GPS painlessly into your project.

What version of the SDK are you using?